# Определить вид грамматической конструкции

Tags: грамматика

Я беспощадно погонял измученного коня, который, хрипя и весь в пене, мчал меня по каменистой дороге.

Какие члены предложения соединяет союз И и можно ли считать их однородными? Насколько стандартна эта грамматическая конструкция? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подразумевающееся «**будучи** в пене» заставляет считать перечисления однородными, хотя «весь в пене мчал» был бы вариантом ближе к стандартному.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант "будучи в пене", который был использован при ответах других участников.

Answer (score 3):

Я беспощадно погонял измученного коня, который, хрипя и весь в пене, мчал меня по каменистой дороге.

Конструкция, конечно, нестандартна, но всё же это сложноподчинённое предложение, придаточное в котором осложнено обособленными однородными обстоятельствами. Мчал как?-хрипя и весь будучи(находясь) в пене.

Comment: А что в ней тогда нестандартного, если вы считаете обстоятельства однородными?

Comment: Нестандартна неполнота распространённого обстоятельства, пропуск деепричастия, что и затрудняет отнесение его к обстоятельству. Чисто внешне похоже на определение.

Comment: А если так: "Я беспощадно погонял измученного коня, который, весь в пене, мчал меня по каменистой дороге". Здесь тоже пропущено деепричастие и это не определение?

Comment: Здесь явное распространённое несогласованное определение,  со слабым значением обстоятельства уступки(мчал, несмотря на то, что весь в пене, на исходе сил). В первом примере обстоятельством его делает именно конструкция с "И", указывающая на однородность. Но это не ошибка, а худ. особенность - использование явления дуплексива. Определение часто бывает со значением обстоятельства причины или уступки.

Comment: Получается, что несогласованное определение, вступив в однородные отношения с обстоятельством, само превратилось в обстоятельство? (Думаю, что дополнительного значения причин или уступки здесь нет)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что  несогласованное определение "весь в пене", вступая в однородные отношения с обстоятельством "хрипя", частично проявляет признаки обстоятельства ("будучи весь в пене"), но при этом остается несогласованным определением, отнесенным к подлежащему.